# How can I check if two properties are not true or false at the same time

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I am using class-validator for validation. I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass {
x: boolean;
y: boolean;
}
```

I need to check that if x is true then y is always false, or if x is false then y is always true. Both of them can't be true or false at the same time. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try validation in this kind of logic by making a strict equality test of one Boolean with the *logical not* of the other, this way:

```
(MyClass.x === !MyClass.y)
//this would mean boolean === !boolean
// in example cases if both x and y are true then the result would be false since true === false (!true) = false.
```

You can then add a condition for validation based on this.